# mysql_insert_id and my woes?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-insert-id

I'm trying to get the auto incremented column of a row. The code will explain, but basically I'm trying to insert a row into a table called orders, and then I want to get the auto incremented number.
This is my PHP.

---

```
<?php

$db = DBConnection::connect();

$q = "INSERT INTO orders (customerid, orderdate) VALUES (".$customerid.", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";

$ps = $db->prepare($q);     
$ps->execute();
$db = null;

echo mysql_insert_id();
?>
```

---

At this stage all I really want to do is echo out the auto number.

This is my structure

---

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `orderid` int(25) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customerid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `orderdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orderid`),
  KEY `orderid` (`orderid`)
)
```

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: Please add a description what your problem is. Does it output the wrong id? Is there an error?

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: I don't seem to be getting an error. I have tried the following:

// public function checkout($customerid){

// $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");

// $selectdb = mysql_select_db("camelio",$con);
     
// mysql_query("INSERT INTO orders (customerid, orderdate) VALUES (".$customerid.", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");

// echo "Last inserted record has id : ". mysql_insert_id(); 
 
// }

My problem is that the output gives a 0, instead of the incremented number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDO is different from `mysql_*` functions.

Since you've used PDO, you must use the method `lastInsertId()` from the PDO object:

```
$db->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: So I should be using something like this?
---
`
    $db = DBConnection::connect();
    $q = "INSERT INTO orders (customerid, orderdate) VALUES (".$customerid.", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
    $ps = $db->prepare($q);
    $ps->execute();
    $db->lastInsertId();
    print $db;
    $db = null;
`
---

Comment: After $ps->execute(), you must use: $last = $db->lastInsertId(); print $last;

Answer (score 3):

DBConnection != MySQL

You can't use functions from different libraries like that. You **must** either change `mysql_num_rows()` to the `DBConnection` equivalent, or change the `DBConnection` stuff to `mysql_*`.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding

```
$ps->execute()
or die(mysql_error());
```

This may show any errors that the database query  is generating